# Bash: Log Time and Command Output on Same Line

Tags: bash, logging

I'm trying to monitor changes on a website, so I want to log a certain element's text and the corresponding timestamp on the same line.

Currently, I can get those logged on two different lines by first running:

```
echo `date` >> log.txt
```

and then running the extraction command (this parses an HTML page to extract the element I care about):

```
cat furby_product_page.html | pup "#productTitle json{}" | jq .[0].text >> log.txt
```

Each time I do this, I'll get a 2-line entry like this:

```
Tue, Jan 22, 2019 8:24:00 PM
"Hasbro Furby Connect Friend, Purple"
```

But I want to see something like this in my log, with timestamp and data on the same line:

```
Tue, Jan 22, 2019 8:24:00 PM "Hasbro Furby Connect Friend, Purple"
Wed, Jan 23, 2019 8:24:00 PM "Hasbro Furby Connect Friend, Purple"
```

How can I get the timestamp and output on the same line in my log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command substitution to capture the output of the two separate commands and echo them on the same line.

```
echo "$(date) $(cat furby_product_page.html | pup '#productTitle json{}' | jq .[0].text)" >> log.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Another (dirty) solution can be `echo` with parameter `-n`. With `-n` parameter, `echo` will not generate a new line, which can be a dirty solution for your current question.

```
echo -n `date`" " >> log.txt # note the space
cat furby_product_page.html | pup "#productTitle json{}" | jq .[0].text >> log.txt
```